# How to create mysql triggers using migrations in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, triggers

Is there a way to create mysql triggers using Activerecord migrations  ?  Has anybody worked on it share your experience . Thanks

Answer (score 23, accepted):

There's no magic method allowing you to create a trigger without writing any SQL.
But you can execute raw sql inside any migration.

```
def self.up
    execute <<-SQL
        CREATE TRIGGER my_trigger ...
    SQL
end
```

Then you just need to appropriately write your trigger or update it depending of the migration.

**Edit** : I've just found [rails_on_pg](http://github.com/alex3t/rails_on_pg/), which provides some helpers to migrations.
It doesn't work with any other database server than PgSQL. But it can be a good lead if you're up to writing some MySQL triggering helper.

Comment: Thanks , for your resource , i wasn't knowing that it did exists :)

Comment: Best remove the reference to `rails_on_pg` now :) it was last updates 6 years ago :)

Comment: The advantage a gem like `hairtrigger` is that it will write your triggers to shcema.rb ensuring your database has them on recreation or in testing.

Answer (score 12):

there's a gem called [hairtrigger](https://github.com/jenseng/hair_trigger) that makes this a little easier and more portable (mysql/sqlite/postgres). it lets you create triggers in your migrations in a db-agnostic way, or even better you can declare them in your models and then run rake db:generate_trigger_migration to do it for you.

Comment: This gem is outdated - supports Rails 2.3 - Rails 3.0.x. But idea is great.

Comment: the gem has been updated to support the latest versions of rails

Comment: Jon your gem is fantastic. Do you know any to generate pg indexes?

Answer (score 0):

Thought it might help someone...

If we put custom SQL it may not work on development environment, if we are using SQLite3 and our migrate command would fail on sqlite:

```
rake db:migrate
```

I found it more useful to create trigger sql in a separate file under db/scripts and execute them in mysql cli. That way I could re-run them as per the need when the trigger changes.